# Copy files from a text list and preserve folder structure

Tags: windows, powershell, copy, synchronization, robocopy

Textfile contains full path of each file, all these need to be copied while preserving folder structure

```
C:\test2\sample2.jpg


G:\test3\folder1\sample3.mov


C:\test6\fol der1 \sample77.iso


D:\test3\folder1\fo  $der2\sample5.mkv
```

New to powershall so this is the code i tried

```
$destination = "C:\copy_folder"
"C:\filelist.txt"

Get-Content $textFileWithPaths | % {
  $NewFolder = Split-Path (Join-Path $destination $_) -Parent | Split-Path -NoQualifier`

  If(!(Test-Path $NewFolder)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewFolder -Force
}
 Copy-Item $_ $NewFolder -Force
}
```

Thanks

Comment: by persevering structure I assume you mean everything after the drive right?

Comment: Yes result should looks like this C:\copy_folder\test2\sample2.jpg

Comment: I've assumed in my answer that your file doesnt have empty lines as you're showing it here, in case it does have empty lines you need a condition to ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I'm seeing is that you're not removing the Root of each path from your file before joining them with their new destination.

Basically, this part:

```
Split-Path (Join-Path $destination $_) -Parent | Split-Path -NoQualifier
```

Should be:

```
Split-Path $_ -NoQualifier | Join-Path $destination -ChildPath { $_ }
```

This should do the trick:

```
$destination = (New-Item C:\copy_folder -ItemType Directory -Force).FullName

Get-Content $textFileWithPaths | ForEach-Object {
    $path = Join-Path $destination $_.Substring([IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($_).Length)
    $null = [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($path))
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_ -Destination $path
}
```